# Pandas .loc with sort_values assignment does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-loc

I am trying to assign a value and/or a series of values to a slice of a pandas dataframe selected using .loc after sorting values.

For reference, this is the code I am trying to run, with a set string value ('filler')

```
df.sort_values(['col_1','col_2']).loc[
    df.col_1.isin(rows_selector),col_2] = 'filler'
```

and with a pandas series containing the different values (the series is of the same length as the output of .loc

```
df.sort_values(['col_1','col_2']).loc[
    df.col_1.isin(rows_selector),col_2] = filler_series
```

I would expect the above to assign the desired values in place in `df`, but that does not seem to happen. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an intermediary step in this for it to work.  While the sorted df called before the loc will be sorted, the df used in the loc (df.col_1.isin()) will still be calling from the unsorted df. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,1,7,5,9,7],
                   'col_2':[4,1,5,6,6,3]})

   col_1  col_2
0      1      4
1      1      1
2      7      5
3      5      6
4      9      6
5      7      3
```

Running `df.sort_values(['col_1','col_2'])` gives:

```
   col_1  col_2
1      1      1
0      1      4
3      5      6
5      7      3
2      7      5
4      9      6
```

However, if you run `df.col_1.isin(rows_selector)` (where `rows_selector = [1, 5, 9]`) returns the following:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: col_1, dtype: bool
```

Notice that the values that are `True` do not sit on the same indexes as the `sort_values` output, as it is still checking the original dataframe.

You should assign the sorted version to be `df`, or `df_sorted` and then use `.loc` on that like this:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(['col_1','col_2'])
df_sorted.loc[df_sorted.col_1.isin(rows_selector)]
   col_1  col_2
1      1      1
0      1      4
3      5      6
4      9      6
```

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment, this uses the `@Emi OB` data)

Some people may prefer to chain all the operations (matter of style). For that, You can always write small ad-hoc functions and use them with `pipe`:

```py
def piping_loc(df, col='col_1', rows_selector = [1, 5, 9]):
     return df.loc[df[col].isin(rows_selector)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,1,7,5,9,7],
                   'col_2':[4,1,5,6,6,3]})

df.sort_values(['col_1','col_2']).pipe(piping_loc)
```

You can pass the functions' arguments to pipe, e.g: `pipe(piping_loc, rows_selector=[1,9])`